# Permutation group equation

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, discrete-mathematics

$\pi^2=(1\ 2\  3\  4\  5),\pi \in S_{5} \\$

where $\pi$ is the cycle. I have calculated the following:
$(1 2 3 4 5)(1 2 3 4 5)^2 = (1 3 5 2 4)(1 3 5 2 4),\\(1 2 3 4 5)(1 2 3 4 5)^3 = (1 4 2 5 3)(1 4 2 5 3)\\(1 2 3 4 5)(1 2 3 4 5)^4 = (1 5 4 3 2)(1 5 4 3 2)$ and after $(1 2 3 4 5)(1 2 3 4 5)^{10}$ I get the identical function. Well $S_{5}$ has $5!$ elements, how can I finish this exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\pi\in S_5$, then it is either the identity element, a 2-cycle, a product of two 2-cycles, a product of a 2-cycle and a 3-cycle, a 4-cycle, or a 5-cycle. Out of all these possibilities, only 5-cycles have the property that the square is also a 5-cycle.

So $\pi$ is a 5-cycle, hence has order 5. Therefore
$$ \pi=\pi^6=(\pi^2)^3 $$
and since you know $\pi^2$ you can now determine $\pi$.